# Java String Regex split and capture splitted portion

Tags: java, regex

Following is the string,
Card 41:
  Slot Type               : SFC
Card 42:
  Slot Type               : PFC
Card 43:
  Slot Type               : GFC
  Operational State       : Empty
Card 44:
  Slot Type               : KFC
Card 45:
  Slot Type               : SFC

i want to split in a way so that i should have a map of (41,SFC),(42,SFC),(43,GFC),(44,KFC)....
currently iam using this regex "\s*Card\s*\d+\s*:", is it possible to split and capture with the same regex, like i mean i want to split with "\s*Card\s*(\d+)\s*:" and capture the (\d+).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of what you want to achieve.

```
String input = "Card 41: Slot Type : SFC Card 42: Slot Type : " +
                "PFC Card 43: Slot Type : GFC Operational State : Empty " +
                "Card 44: Slot Type : KFC Card 45: Slot Type : SFC";
//                           | starts with "Card"
//                           |   | any white space
//                           |   |   | group 1: any digits
//                           |   |   |     | any characters, reluctantly
//                           |   |   |     |  | group 2: looking for 3 capital letter characters
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Card\\s+(\\d+).+?([A-Z]{3})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
// key set of map will be ordered lexicographically
// if you want to retain insertion order instead, use LinkedHashMap
// for better performance, just a HashMap
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
// iterate over find
while (m.find()) {
    map.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
System.out.println(map);
```

**Output**

```
{41=SFC, 42=PFC, 43=GFC, 44=KFC, 45=SFC}
```

Answer (score 1):

### To Tokenize, use Capture Groups

This regex will parse your string:

```
Card (\d+): Slot Type : (\w+)
```

As you can see in the **right pane** of the **[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cX0zG2/2)**, capture Groups 1 and 2 contain the tuples you want.

**Sample Java Code**

Here is how to retrieve your tuples:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("Card (\\d+): Slot Type : (\\w+)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // The Card
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.group(1));
    // The Slot Type
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.group(2));
}
```

Of course instead of printing the values, you can assign them to any data structure you like.

**Explanation**

- `Card` matches literal chars
- `(\d+)` captures the number to Group 1
- `: Slot Type :` matches literal chars
- `(\w+)` captures the slot type to Group 2

Answer (score 0):

`Card (\d+):.+?: ?(\w+)` should do the trick with the global modifier.

- `(\d+)` captures the digits after `Card`
- `(\w+)` captures the letters after the second semicolon

[Demo on RexEx101](http://regex101.com/r/xA4tD2/1)