# Split on regex and capture matched delimiter expression in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am trying to parse a text file which has a series of "records" that start with a number (followed by a NBSP and 1-2 spaces), contain several hundred characters of letters and numbers, span line breaks, but don't end with anything predictable. The only way to identify the end of the record is to hit the next instance of the starting marker, which can be matched by the following regex:

```
\\d{1,4}\\u00A0\\s+
```

The content was hand entered, with unpredictable line breaks, so I stripped them out. That leaves me with a string.

```
1  blah blah blah  2  blah blah blah ... 875  blah blah blah
```

Since the only way I know that a record has ended is by hitting the next record ID, I tried just splitting on the regex above.  That splits the file into the records correctly, but it omits the record ID, which I need to capture. I checked the Java docs, but there's nothing on capturing the dynamic value being split on. I tried making the record number a capture group, but that data isn't retained in the resulting array.

This question ([Java String Regex split and capture splitted portion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057141/java-string-regex-split-and-capture-splitted-portion)) seems similar, but the asker knows where each text fragment ends; whereas I only know where each begins.

So is there an alternative way to split, but retain the text match by the split regex?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just check if after your text some other text exists but without including that other text in your match (like checking if after `foo` is `bar` but without including `bar` in match) then you are looking for [look-around mechanism](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) or to be more precise, positive look ahead `(?=...)`.

So lets start with `split("(?=\\d{1,4}\\u00A0\\s+)")`. This will split before any series of 1-4 digits which have NBSP after it and some whitespaces. Problem with this is that for text like

```
1234[nbsp]___
```

this describes places (marked with `|`)

```
|1234[nbsp]___ 
1|234[nbsp]___ 
12|34[nbsp]___ 
123|4[nbsp]___
```

But we don't want to allow splitting between digits. We must add condition to prevent such split. So it would be nice if we could say "there can't be digit before place of split". To do this we can use negative look behind `(?<!...)` which in our case will look like `(?<!\\d)`.

***So final solution can look like***:

```
split("(?<!\\d)(?=\\d{1,4}\\u00A0\\s+)")
```

Comment: Ah. Very nice.

For posterity:  This method of splitting allowed me to retain the dynamic delimiter matched by the regex in each split line.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `split()`, but write your own regex loop, e.g.

```
String input = "...your input...";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,4}\\u00A0\\s+").matcher(input);
int prev = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    String prevText = input.substring(prev, m.start());
    prev = m.end();
    String delimiter = m.group();
    // ... code here ...
}
String tailText = input.substring(prev); // text after last delimiter
// ... code here ...
```

Comment: Variant: `Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\d{1,4}\\u00A0\\s+)", Pattern.DOTALL); while (m.find()) { String prevText = m.group(1); String delimiter = m.group(2); ... }`. Or, if you care about the unterminated bit at the end: `String delimiter; Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\d{1,4}\\u00A0\\s+|$)", Pattern.DOTALL); while (! "".equals(delimiter)) { m.find(); String prevText = m.group(1); delimiter = m.group(2); ... }`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe First part is useless, because you definitely care about tail text, given that the delimiter is a prefix, not a terminator. --- For second part, you just caused an `IllegalStateException`, because that's what happens when calling [`group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-) after `find()` returns false. Says so right there in the javadoc. --- Well, I mean, that's what would happen after somehow fixing the compilation error of `delimiter` not being initialized.

Comment: `find()` shouldn't return false, because I added `|$` into the regex so it should still match at the end without a delimiter. And change `String delimiter;` to `String delimiter = null;`.